# Error C2665 and C2039 when building OpenJDK on Windows

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble building the current OpenJDK (17-LTS and 20) on Windows. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition and the latest Cygwin release.
First of all *bash configure* with options for client and server variant runs well. I'm also able to build the server variant but compiling the native code of the client always shows compiling errors (see below). Before coming here, I've researched a lot for the errors and tried other VS Studio Version (2017/2019). I also tried compiling with different options such as not using precompiled headers etc. I know my problems fall into little niche but maybe someone experienced similar problems and can help. ANd just in case someone is curious why I'm not using the binary releases provided by Adoptium and so on. We try to change the native code to add optimization for our Java processes we run on a daily basis.

**Exceptions from log:**

```
c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/g1/g1ThreadLocalData.hpp(41): error C2665: "SATBMarkQueue::SATBMarkQueue": Keine überladene Funktion konnte alle Argumenttypen konvertieren
c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/shared/satbMarkQueue.hpp(84): note: kann "SATBMarkQueue::SATBMarkQueue(const SATBMarkQueue &)" sein
c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/g1/g1ThreadLocalData.hpp(41): note: "SATBMarkQueue::SATBMarkQueue(const SATBMarkQueue &)" : Konvertierung von Argument 1 von "G1SATBMarkQueueSet *" in "const SATBMarkQueue &" nicht möglich

c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/g1/g1ThreadLocalData.hpp(41): note: Die Typen, auf die verwiesen wird, sind unabhängig; die Konvertierung erfordert eine reinterpret_cast-Umwandlung, eine C-Stil-Umwandlung oder eine in Klammern gesetzte Umwandlung im Funktionsstil.
c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/g1/g1ThreadLocalData.hpp(41): note: bei Anpassung der Argumentliste "(G1SATBMarkQueueSet *)"
Hinweis: Einlesen der Datei:     c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/shared/accessBarrierSupport.inline.hpp
Hinweis: Einlesen der Datei:      c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/shared/accessBarrierSupport.hpp
c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/g1/g1BarrierSet.inline.hpp(42): error C2039: "is_active" ist kein Member von "G1SATBMarkQueueSet".
c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/g1/g1SATBMarkQueueSet.hpp(33): note: Siehe Deklaration von "G1SATBMarkQueueSet"
c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/g1/g1BarrierSet.inline.hpp(45): error C2039: "enqueue_known_active" ist kein Member von "G1SATBMarkQueueSet".
c:\development\jdk20\src\hotspot\share\gc/g1/g1SATBMarkQueueSet.hpp(33): note: Siehe Deklaration von "G1SATBMarkQueueSet"
```